# Fourier and Bessel

Tags: ho.history-overview, special-functions, reference-request, fourier-analysis

Oliver Heaviside, on page 387 of *Electrical Papers*, Vol. I, Macmillan and Co., 1892, available [here](http://archive.org/stream/electricalpapers01heavuoft#page/386/mode/2up), writes

$$v = 1 - \frac{n^2r^2}{2^2} + \frac{n^4r^4}{2^2 4^2} - \frac{n^6r^6}{2^24^26^2} + \ldots = J_0(nr)$$

and

**This function is usually denoted by $J_0(nr)$, and was first employed by Fourier. Whether he invented it or discovered it is a doubtful point; the question is raised whether mathematical truths lie within the human mind alone, or whether the infinite body of known and unknown mathematics could exist in a dead universe. But this is metaphysics, which is all vanity and vexation of spirit.**

Heaviside gives no reference.

I have two questions:

1. Are there any references in the Fourier work about the symbol $J_0()$ ?
2. What does the letter $J$ stand for?

Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: According to Cajori's history of mathematical notation, Bessel used the letter I and Hansen changed it to J.  If this is true, then it almost certainly has nothing to do with the J in Joseph Fourier.

Comment: Incidentally, Dutka's article "On the early history of Bessel functions" (http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00376544) does not seem to discuss the naming issue, but goes back even further than Fourier (to the Bernoullis and Euler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fundamental reference using Bessel functions in Fourier's works. This is ["Théorie analytique de la chaleur"](http://books.google.it/books?id=TDQJAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q&f=false) firstly published on 1822. You will find this series firstly given in chapter VI pag. 370. This chapter is about the propagation of the heat in a cylinder ("of course" let me add).

The modern nomenclature was invented by Bessel himself on 1824, just two years after Fourier's work. This is proved in [F. Bessel, "Untersuchung des Theils der planetarischen Störungen", Berlin Abhandlungen (1824)](http://edoc.bbaw.de/volltexte/2008/735/pdf/21hekEZuXxSQ.pdf). Here the functions I and J get their names.

Comment: Of course, Jon! Thanks! Unfortunately, the symbol $J_0()$ is not used in "Théorie" ...

Comment: You are right but I will fix it.

Comment: +1 on the "of course" (of course).

Comment: Actually, the 1824 Bessel paper does not quite use the modern notation.  Instead, it uses $I$ where we use $J$.  For example, the table on page 46 shows $J_0(k)$ and $J_1(k)$ in modern notation.

Comment: @Henry: Nice comment. But the first use is surely there.